# ¿Como realizar una inserción a tabla en Dynamo BD desde un web servicie en C# de manera dinámica con ajuste de tipo de datos?

Tags: c#, aws, signalr, dynamodb

Necesito crear un servicio para un mensajero entre plataformas. Este servicio debe registrar los mensajes que pasan por su canal de comunicación en una tabla DynamoDB.

El problema que tengo aquí es que no se cómo plantear el diseño del servicio para que el registro de los diferentes mensajes pueda encajar en esa tabla de DynamoDB.

Comment: Los aportes se agradecen, pero el formato esperado es: pregunta por un lado y respuesta por otro. Mezclar ambas en el apartado de la pregunta no va a ser de mucha ayuda. Edita la pregunta para dejar ... justamente eso, una pregunta. Después crea una respuesta y añade ahí la parte que corresponda a la respuesta

Comment: Tienes razón, voy a modificar mi aporte

Answer (score 0):

**Quiero realizar un aporte a la comunidad...**
Hace un tiempo requería un servicio (Socket) para un mensajero entre plataformas que registrara los mensajes que pasaran por su canal de comunicación, el servicio esta montado en un servidor EC2 y tiene expuesto una IP con un puerto fijo, se requería que los registro estuvieran guardados en tablas de DynamoDB, para no tener un método por cada tabla y por cada modelo que se recibiera se creo un método dinámico que podía recibir un objeto genérico para construir la Query en base a ese objeto.

```
  public async Task<T> PostItem<T>(string tableName, T Value)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Value == null ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName))
            {
                return default;
            }
            //se crea el modelo a guardar          
            var items = ModelCreator(Value);

            //Estructura de peticion
            var request = new PutItemRequest(tableName: tableName, item: items);
            //Accion BD
            var response = client.PutItemAsync(request);
            if (response.Result.HttpStatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                response.Result.HttpStatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
                if (response.Result.Attributes.Count > 0)
                {
                    var objectJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Result.Attributes);
                    T jsonDeserialize = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(objectJson);
                    return jsonDeserialize;
                }
                return default;
                /*foreach (Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> item in response.Result.Items)
                {
                    // Process the result.
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }*/
            }
            else
            {
                return default;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error PostItem: " + e.Message);
            return default;
        }
    }
```

> Para la construcción del modelo genérico que se le manda al PostAsync en base en un DTO cualquiera que requiere considerar los tipos de datos y a su ves la key con el nombre que no se sabe hasta el tiempo de ejecución se creo el siguiente metodo.

```
 public Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> ModelCreator<T>(T Value)
    {
        try
        {
            Type tModelType = Value.GetType();
            var items = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>();//Dto Pricipal
            var items2 = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>();//Map secundario(Interno)
                         
            //We will be defining a PropertyInfo Object which contains details about the class property 
            PropertyInfo[] arrayPropertyInfos = tModelType.GetProperties();

            //Now we will loop in all properties one by one to get value
            foreach (PropertyInfo property in arrayPropertyInfos)
            {
                //Se evealua que no sea de tipo Map, el tipo Map no se puede identifacar pero si los otros tipos de datos.
                if (property.GetValue(Value) != null &&
                    property.GetValue(Value).GetType().Name != "String" &&
                    property.GetValue(Value).GetType().Name != "Int32" &&
                    property.GetValue(Value).GetType().Name != "Int64" &&
                    property.GetValue(Value).GetType().Name != "Boolean")
                {
                    Type tModelType2 = property.GetValue(Value).GetType();
                    //Type tModelType2 = property.GetType();

                    //We will be defining a PropertyInfo Object which contains details about the class property 
                    PropertyInfo[] arrayPropertyInfos2 = tModelType2.GetProperties();
                    //Now we will loop in all properties one by one to get value
                    foreach (PropertyInfo property2 in arrayPropertyInfos2)
                    {
                        await();
                        //items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue(property2.GetValue(Value).ToString()));
                        switch (property2.GetMethod.ReturnType.Name)
                        {
                            case "String":
                                //Si llega vacio se le agrega un "" para egregarlo como Empy
                                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)).ToString()))
                                {
                                    //items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue(property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)).ToString()));
                                    items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue { S = property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)).ToString() });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue(""));
                                    items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue { S = "" });
                                }
                                break;
                            case "Int32":
                                if (property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)).ToString() != "0")
                                {
                                    items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue { N = property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)).ToString() });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Se recibio una valor numerico Int32 sin valor asignado");
                                }                                    
                                break;
                            case "Int64":
                                if (property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)).ToString() != "0")
                                {
                                    items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue { N = property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)).ToString() });
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Se recibio una valor numerico Int64 sin valor asignado");
                                }                                    
                                break;
                            case "Boolean":
                                items2.Add(property2.Name, new AttributeValue { BOOL = (bool)property2.GetValue(property.GetValue(Value)) });
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Error ModelCreator: No se identifica el tipo de archivo para agregar al modelo");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    //var a = (Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>)items2;
                    items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue { M = items2 });
                    await();
                    items2.Clear();//Se limpia para agregar valores para otro Map
                   
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (property.GetValue(Value).GetType().Name)
                    {
                        case "String":
                            //Si llega vacio se le agrega un "" para egregarlo como Empy
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(property.GetValue(Value).ToString()))
                            {
                                //items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue(property.GetValue(Value).ToString()));
                                items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue { S = property.GetValue(Value).ToString() });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue(""));
                                items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue { S = "" });
                            }
                            break;
                        case "Int32":
                            if (property.GetValue(Value).ToString() != "0")
                            {
                                items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue { N = property.GetValue(Value).ToString() });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Se recibio una valor numerico Int32 sin valor asignado");
                            }                               
                            break;
                        case "Int64":
                            if (property.GetValue(Value).ToString() != "0")
                            {
                                items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue { N = property.GetValue(Value).ToString() });
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Se recibio una valor numerico Int64 sin valor asignado");
                            }                                
                            break;
                        case "Boolean":
                            items.Add(property.Name, new AttributeValue { BOOL = (bool)property.GetValue(Value) });
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Error ModelCreator: No se identifica el tipo de archivo para agregar al modelo");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return items;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error ModelCreator: " + e.Message);
            return default;
        }
    }
    public async void await()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

> Espero les pueda aportar algo, y sus mejoras son bien recibidas.
> .

Comment: Aunque tu aporte se agradece, la pregunta no cumple como pregunta.. y lo que aportas, aunque interesante, no resuelve ningun problema porque no esta en la pregunta. El sitio es para problemas concretos, con respuestas a esos problemas concretos.. vos estas mostrando un metodo desarrollado.. que seria mejor para un blog.. tomate el tiempo de hacer el [tour] y tambien mirar [ask] asi entiendes como funciona el sitio...

Comment: De paso.. mirando el codigo.. porque tenes un metodo await que para todo 1 segundo a cada rato? porque hay un if con dos switch que hacen exactamente lo mismo? que pasa con todos los otros tipos de datos?